# Why don't counts using 'LIKE' in SQL match?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have one table `ABC` with `EMPLID`, `GRADE`, `SALARY` and `DATE` as its fields.

I am executing the following 3 statements:

```
select count(*) from ABC;
```

Result :- 458

```
select count(*) from ABC where GRADE LIKE '%def%';
```

Result :- 0

```
select count(*) from ABC where GRADE NOT LIKE '%def%';
```

Result :- 428

My point here is: the result of second query plus the result of third query should be equal to the result of first query, shouldn't it?

Comment: seems you have some null values on the `GRADE` column on your table

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you have 30 records where the GRADE is `null`.

`null` values are unknown, so do not match either condition.

Comment: Try running this query:  `select * from ABC where grade is null`.

Answer (score 3):

Sql uses a three-valued logic: true, false &unknown. If you compare a NULL to any other value the result is unknown. NOT(unknown) is still unknown.

A WHERE clause only returns rows that evaluate to true. So the missing 30 rows in your example have a NULL in the Grade column.

Comment: Thanks, I got the 3 valued logic here but the point I want to understand here is that Why NOT(Unknown) is still unknown??

Answer (score 2):

Note that apart from the obvious case where you can have `NULL` values in your table (as others have mentioned), you could also have empty strings.

In [Oracle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/11641):

```
-- Returns nothing
select 1 from dual where '' like '%'
```

In [MySQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/13291):

```
-- Returns 1
select 1 from dual where '' like '%'
```

Since you tagged your question with both [oracle](/questions/tagged/oracle) and [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql), you might be running into an incompatibility here, as in oracle `'' IS NULL` holds true!

Comment: Thanks for such a useful point here.. I dint considered that hereI am using Oracle so must have mentioned..